# Array of class with a const member in C++

Tags: c++

I want to initialize an array of class which contains a const member that must be initialize at construction.

```
#include <iostream>
class A
{
    private:
        const int var_;

    public:
        A(const int var) : var_(var){};

        int getVar(){return var_;}
};

class B
{
    private:
        A tab[2];

    public:
        B() : tab{2,5} {}; // The trick should be here, I think !

        int getA(int index) { return tab[index].getVar();}
};

int main(void)
{

    B b; // constraint : Dynamic allocation not allowed
    std::cout << b.getA(0) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This code does not compile because the constructor for class B is not right.
Thanks for your help,
Nicolas

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: What does it say when it doesn't compile? (Error?)

Comment: Does the compile just say "not right", or does it give a few details? If it gives details tell us.

Comment: This compiles fine for me. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: Bad french translation, I meant array not table.

Comment: Compiler message : `error: bad array initializer`

Comment: @Jimbo you are right, it is the same question. Sorry for that.

Comment: @boutboutnico: no worries, it was an interesting question. I didn't know the answer but have learnt something too :)

Answer (score 0):

The command

`g++ -std=c++11 1.cpp`

compiles the code above just fine. Running `1.exe` prints `2` in the console.

P.S: g++.EXE (GCC) 4.9.0 20130616 (experimental)

Comment: I cannot used c++11 but thanks.

Comment: Your code uses C++11 features.